# How to update an entity with many children entities, in a safe way, using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `users` that has some associated tables : `books`, `cars`,  etc.

In my application, a user and all his associated entities are updated *at once*. For example, a book is added to the user, another book is deleted, the "name" field of the user itself is changed, and *then* the application saves the user in the database.

To save this new version of the user, I currently:

- Start a transaction (using the default isolation level).
- `UPDATE` the fields of the user himself (here, his "name").
- Use a `MERGE` for all his associated entities, to update them.
- Commit the transaction.

*Example: the **"Books" query** (excluding the join table)*

```
MERGE INTO books WITH (HOLDLOCK)
USING (
  VALUES ${valuesClause}
) AS actualRow(id, title, author)
ON books.id = actualRow.id

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET 
  books.title = actualRow.title,
  books.author = actualRow.author

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
  INSERT (title, author) 
  VALUES (actualRow.title, actualRow.author)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
  DELETE

OUTPUT inserted.id as insertedId, deleted.id as deletedId
```

(Note that the "`${valuesClause}`" part is actually generated by my application, using the current books of the user.)

As you can see, I use a "`WITH (HOLDLOCK)`" hint which seems to be the recommended way to make sure a `MERGE` is safe. I've read a lot about `MERGE` in SQL Server and how it can lead to race conditions and other issues if you are not careful [[example]](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx).

But I also read that those kind of inline table hints will apply a lock *for the entire duration of the transaction they are in*. If this is correct, the "`HOLDLOCK`" will apply locks on the `books` table until the whole user is updated and the *initial transaction* is actually commited.

But since a user has multiple associated entities to be updated, I use this `MERGE with HOLDLOCK` pattern multiple times when updating a single user. And since I'm using the three conditions in each of them ("`WHEN MATCHED`", "`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`" and "`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`"), I'm afraid updating a user will lock *way too many rows*, for too long, and performances will suffer.

**My question**: is my approach correct to save a user and all his related entities? If I want to stay 100% safe in a potentially high load environment, what other approach would you suggest to update a whole user?

I use (and have to use) SQL Server 2014 SP2.

Comment: The fact that locks are taken and held for the duration of the transaction is not generally a problem if there are no parallel updates to the same rows (barring lock escalation). If there are, then obviously you'll get contention, but that's more or less the contention you want, to prevent conflicts. In general, it's far better to write the code transactionally correct, then test to see if there are possibly issues under load, then it is to try getting clever and weaken the locks in advance when this could lead to hard to solve conflicts and deadlocks.

Comment: If you *do* see problems under load, then `MERGE` usually becomes an albatross and you're better off splitting things into their own `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` statements, as it's easier to control the lock granularity on separate statements. `MERGE` is convenient, but also does a lot of invisible heavy lifting that's overkill for most simple scenarios, especially if you "know" particular statements "can't affect" others (knowledge which `MERGE` cannot exploit).

Comment: I'd like to note that your data points and changes seem to be fairly isolated to the individual user; locking everything and doing a merge seems like overkill unless you're worried about modifications to large cross-user sets of data.

Comment: I think you may be right and that, in my scenario, I do not really have to add that extra lock protection. Even if there are some load, I doubt there will be lors of load to update the same entities at the same time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Do you have a link to an example of using `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` statements with locks instead of a `MERGE` as I do? I only find examples involving a "`if exists`" to simulate an `UPSERT`, but no example with the `DELETE` part... Thanks for your help!

Comment: My main fear is that using all three conditions in the MERGE : "`WHEN MATCHED`", "`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET`" and "`WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`" will lock almost *all rows* of the table, for the duration of the whole transaction!! Once a particular `MERGE` is done, will the lock only stay active *on the affected rows*, or *on all rows that were needed to be scanned*? Because it seems a full `OUTER JOIN` is required in my case : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: How do you associate books with users? You need a `DELETE books WHERE User = ... AND ID NOT IN (SELECT IDs FROM @TableWithAllIDsForThisUser)` or suchlike, but your question doesn't have enough details to fill in the blanks. Note that `DELETE` (and the other queries) support additional `FROM` and `JOIN` as well, although this gets complicated, and it's usually simpler to construct a CTE (`WITH BooksToDelete AS (SELECT * FROM books WHERE ...) DELETE BooksToDelete`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wrote a comment about the "join" part being missing ("*(excluding the join table)*"), maybe it's not clear enough though... You are absolutlely right that this part is missing in my `MERGE` example. I should update my example.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your example. I would still like to see a full example involving locks though!

Comment: If all the statements are wrapped in a transaction, the only real lock you need is a `HOLDLOCK` (aka `SERIALIZABLE`) on the initial `UPDATE` of the user. This lock will serve as a global lock on the rest of the data, ensuring no other transaction can proceed until this one is done updating the user as a whole (but without blocking updates on other users). The other statements can proceed under `READ COMMITTED` (that is, with no special hints). The transaction as a whole is still necessary to provide all-or-nothing semantics.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks again for your help. You should write a proper "answer", if you want, and I would accept it.